# The overheads of using setInterval to get latest data from database

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, database

im creating a messaging feature that gets the latest messages from a database every few seconds, basically this method does a continuous database search in order to display new messages.

**example of the code:**

```
 function getLatestActivities(){
    var ignoreMessagesArr = $("input.activityId").map(function(){ return this.value; }).get().join(",");
    var profileId = $("input#userActivityId").val();

    $.ajax({
        traditional: true,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET", url: "include/process.php", 
        data:{
            getLatestActivity: "true",
            toUser: profileId,
            ignoreMessages: ignoreMessagesArr
        },
        success: function(data){
            $.each(data, function (i, elem) {
                $('.commentMessage').after(elem.value);
            });              
        }
    });   
}
```

What I want to know is whether there is a more efficient way of performing this task, i.e. detecting a change in the database instead(???).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want your web app to receive data when it changes in the database, but not necessarily to send data in real time. If two way communication is required then you are looking for Web Sockets which [Socket.IO](http://socket.io) will help you with server side but requires that you run a [Node](http://nodejs.org) server. There is a Google code project that enables Web Sockets for PHP called [PHPWebSocket](http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/) but, if I remember right, requires that you run it in a separate process (i.e. run it from the command line). So that kind of takes care of the server part, but now you have to worry about the front-end.

Currently only FireFox and Chrome fully support Web Sockets [according to CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=websockets). For those browsers lacking support you need a polyfill. [Here is a list of HTML5 polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills). So Web Sockets can be sort of a mess to implement, so make sure that's what you want to do.

On the other hand if your webapp only needs to receive data then EventSource (a.k.a. Server Sent Events) is the way to go. [The support is better](http://caniuse.com/#search=eventsource) on the front-end and you don't really have to do much on the server. Again, for less than stellar browsers you will need a polyfill, but that pretty much just means IE. See the following sites/tutorials on how to use this feature.

- http://my.opera.com/WebApplications/blog/show.dml/438711
- http://dsheiko.com/weblog/html5-and-server-sent-events
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/

If none of that works there are a few options. Constant polling using some kind of repeating structure like setTimeout, long polling (a.k.a. hanging get) where the server leaves the AJAX request open until there is new data, and there's also the infinite iframe trick, or maybe even a Flash plugin that connects to the server to get data.

Comment: Well I'm creating a social networking style website, it has a profile comment area and it has a chat area. people have been saying that I should use websocket and i've just been looking around and like you said some browsers lack support, i really want maximuim support for multiple browsers just like facebook and twitter.

Comment: If you wanted to see what the person was typing while they were typing it then I would use Web Sockets. Otherwise I would use EventSource to receive messages and normal AJAX to send messages.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) it's geared toward realtime communications with the server. Then you can design the backend to push data to the client when it's available rather than constantly polling the database for new information from the frontend

Answer (score 1):

[HTML5 Web Sockets](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/) allows for two way communication between the client and your server...

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should request only the last `ID` inserted in your database and add it as a parameter to to your ajax request.

`process.php` should handle that `ID` and if there are other rows to do the search.

like

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `ID` FROM `table` WHERE `ID`>'$lastId'");
$result = mysql_num_rows(); //use that to see if you have new rows.
```